# Sencha Touch Packaging for Apple Devices

Tags: iphone, ipad, mobile, extjs, native

When trying to load my sencha touch 2 test application to devices like iPhone and iPad, i receive the following error messages:

> The application was successfully packaged
>
> codesign_allocate: for architecture armv7 object: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/build//testApp.app/stbuild_template malformed object (unknown load command 8)
>   ../build//testApp.app: object file format invalid or unsuitable
>
> Failed to execute system command while signing application with error 256
>
> Failed to package application

I have created the appropriate provision certificates, apple id, .pem file and .p12 file; i have followed the instructions given on sencha's API [website](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/native_packaging)

I have also found Youtube videos explaining the process from start to finish and everything seems to work until the last step. I tried to google the error messages but the answers i received were not very explicit with a lot of "maybe"s

I am running Mac OSX version 10.6.8 with xcode version 4.0.2. Any concrete suggestions would be greatly appreciated as i have been on this for 2 days

thank you

Comment: Did you sort out the issue?

Comment: no, sorry :( i dropped sencha touch and moved towards phonegap!